# ProcessBuilder prints an empty output after do while loop

Tags: java, output, processbuilder

I am using `ProcessBuilder` to open a text file in **Notepad window** and to open another Notepad window with the processed text according to my code.

> What is happening right now is that program opens 1st notepad window
>   with a text I put in it but 2nd windows comes up empty.

Would anyone suggest where do I need to make changes to have processed text printed in 2nd notepad window? (I included the output below the code). I have the right result printed in the console but not in the notepad window. I have never used ProcessBuilder  before and could find only simple examples of how to use it. Appreciate your advice.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the input file: ");
    String inputFileName = in.next();
    System.out.print("Enter the output file: ");
    String outputFileName = in.next();

    String poemFilename = "poem.txt";
    String poemoutFilenamo = "newpoem";
    int lineNum = 1;

    File poemFile = new File(poemFilename);
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(poemFile);
    PrintWriter fileout = new PrintWriter(poemoutFilenamo);

    System.out.printf("Read in %s.\nWrote out %s.\n",inputFileName, outputFileName );

    ProcessBuilder Poemin = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad.exe", poemFilename);
    Poemin.start();

    if (fileIn.hasNextLine()) { 
        do {
            String line = fileIn.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("/*" + lineNum + "*/ %s\n", line);
            lineNum++;
        } while (fileIn.hasNextLine());;

        ProcessBuilder Poemout = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad.exe", poemoutFilenamo);
        Poemout.start();
    } 

    in.close();
    fileIn.close();
    fileout.close();
```

Should print out in Notepad window this:

```
/*1*/ Somewhere over the rainbow
/*2*/ Way up high
/*3*/ And the dreams that you dreamed of
/*4*/ Once in a lullaby
```

Comment: Move `fileout.close()` to ***before*** where you start the 2nd process builder's process. You need to flush to the file before trying to use it, and it needs to be editable (not in use) as well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried it and it still brings up empty window :(

Answer (score 0):

You never write anything to `fileout`.  You created the file but it is empty.

I believe you want

```
fileout.printf("/*" + lineNum + "*/ %s\n", line);
```

And also you need to close `fileout` ***before*** launching the second process.